# Dependent types: Crossing the type/kind (runtime/compiletime) barrier

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, data-kinds

While venturing deeper into Haskell's dependent types I keep bumping into problems with the strict separation of run-time and compile-time checks.

Let me demonstrate the issue(s) with a little example of integers with a given bit-length.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators #-}
import GHC.TypeNats
import Data.Bits

data Sign = Signed | Unsigned

data Int_ (s::Sign) (n::Nat) where
    Int_  :: Integer -> Int_ Signed n
    UInt_  :: Integer -> Int_ Unsigned n
```

It's a type `Int s n` with signature `s` and bit-length `n`.
Some useful class instances would look like this:

```
instance (KnownNat n) => Show (Int_ s n) where
    -- Verilog style
    show i@(Int_ v)  = (show.natVal) i <> "'sd" <> show v
    show i@(UInt_ v) = (show.natVal) i <> "'ud" <> show v

instance (KnownNat n) => Eq (Int_ s n) where
    (Int_ u) == (Int_ v) = u==v
    (UInt_ u) == (UInt_ v) = u==v
```

Smart constructors that check bounds are

```
int8 :: Integer -> Int_ Signed 8
int8 i = if i<2^7 && i>=(-2^7) then Int_ i else error "int8 Overflow"

uint8 :: Integer -> Int_ Unsigned 8
uint8 i = if i>=0 && i<2^8 then UInt_ i else error "uint8 Overflow"
```

These smart constructors are already not so nice because the sanity check against overflow happens at run-time.

**Problem 1:** I have no clue how to write a smart constructor that would stop me from creating silly ints at compile-time. Moreover I'd need two types of constructors, one with the run-time check and one with the compile-time check.

This 'duplication' problem, that is needing one set of operations with run-time checks and another set of operations for compile-time checks is quite common.

For example, a concatenation operation would look like this:

```
(.++) :: (KnownNat m, KnownNat n) => Int_ Unsigned m 
         -> Int_ Unsigned n -> Int_ Unsigned (m+n)
i@(UInt_ x) .++ j@(UInt_ y) = UInt_ (x*2^(natVal j)+y)
```

and here's a shift operation:

```
(.>>) :: Int_ s m -> Int -> Int_ s m
i@(UInt_ x) .>> n = UInt_ (x `quot` (2 ^ n))
i@(Int_ x) .>> n = Int_ (x `quot` (2 ^ n))
```

It's a sensible definition, but it would also be sensible to let `.>>` return a truncated `Int_ s k` (for the left shift it would in fact be the more sensible thing to do). I.e.

```
(.>>) :: Int_ s m -> Nat n -> Int_ s (m-n)  -- not proper syntax
```

It clearly isn't as simple as that: `m-n` can't be negative - coming back to the bounds check problem above.

**Problem 2**, a fundamental one, I believe, is that sometimes I know the `n` to shift by at compile-time, and sometimes I don't. When I do know the `n` at compile-time I'd like to have the compile-time checks. When `n` is dynamic (determined at run-time) I obviously can't have them. Is there a way to set this up in order to mix-and-match, so to speak, i.e. avoid the duplication of all the logic, one at the value-level and one at the type level, plus the glue between the two?

My hunch is that I need some type class that introduces polymorphism over `Int` and some `Nat` sort of thing, but I'm totally unsure where this is going.

Comment: If you really want to reuse the same logic, Template Haskell seems to be the only way: run the smart constructor at compile time, then quote the result into the code.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I see your point. If at all possible I'd like to avoid TH, though.

Comment: You are asking a lot of Haskell's type system.  Maybe you want to use a language with proper dependent types like Idris?

Comment: This link https://blog.jle.im/entry/practical-dependent-types-in-haskell-2.html might throw some light on the second problem.